# How to implement custom Javascript to my site

Tags: customization, javascript, code

I have been given the following code to implement a siteskin onto our site. It's custom code but I can't work out how to implement the code into my theme (Newspaper) we have custom Javascript/Advert sections in the theme pannel. I noticed that one section asks for the "Script" tags to be removed I removed the  bits but it didn't make a difference! Can you help? 
The code formatted badly earlier so attached a screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Localize script in WordPress

```
<?php

// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

You can find more details here, [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script)

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom javascript this way ...

```
function your_theme_js(){
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      ad4game_siteskin = {}
   </script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'your_theme_js',99);
```